# Exercise about prime ideals

Tags: ring-theory

Let $A$ be a ring. Prove that the following conditions are equivalent:

$i)$  All ideals $I \subsetneq A$ are prime.

$ii)$ The set of all ideals of $A$ is totally ordered by
inclusion and all ideals of $A$ are idempotent.

Please give me a hint. I dont see the relation between these two statemens.

Comment: Just to double-check, we are not assuming that $A$ is commutative, correct?

Comment: No ,A is not necesary commutative

Answer (score 4):

First suppose the ideals are linearly ordered and they are all idempotent.

We will show that a proper ideal $C\lhd R$ is prime: Let $A,B$ be two other ideals such that $AB\subseteq C$. By way of contradiction, suppose that neither $A$ nor $B$ are contained in $C$. By the linear order, the three form a chain with $C$ at the bottom, so, without loss of generality, we suppose $C\subseteq B\subseteq A$. But then $C\supseteq AB\supseteq BB=B$. This contradicts the statement that $B$ is not contained in $C$. Thus, $C$ is prime.

---

The other direction is easy of course! Suppose all proper ideals of $R$ are prime.

Firstly, for any ideal $A$, $A^2$ is prime. But then by primeness $A\subseteq A^2$, so that $A=A^2$.

Secondly, given two ideals $A,B$, the product $AB$ is a prime ideal. But by primeness, either $A\subseteq AB$ or $B \subseteq AB$. In the first case, $A\subseteq AB\subseteq B$ and in the second, $B\subseteq AB\subseteq A$.

---

Considering the classic commutative theory result (A commutative ring in which all proper ideals are prime is a field."), this exercise shows that the direct noncommutative analogue ("All ideals prime implies division ring???") is not going to hold." Of course, any full square matrix ring $M_n(F)$  over a field ($n>1$) has only one proper ideal, which is prime, and this shows that such a ring does not have to be a division ring.

But with a suitable definition of a prime right ideal the result can be saved! In Lam and Reyes's excellent paper [*A one-sided prime ideal principle for noncommutative rings*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.5295v4.pdf) such a definition of "prime right ideal" is given, and it's an elementary result shown there that a ring whose right ideals are all prime in this way is a division ring. (Actually the paper is full of much more interesting results, and I just can't resist plugging it here.)

Answer (score 1):

Assume (i).
Let $\mathfrak a,\mathfrak b\subsetneq A$ be two ideals and assume $\mathfrak a$ is not contained in $\mathfrak b$, i.e. there exists $a\in\mathfrak a\setminus \mathfrak b$. Then for $b\in\mathfrak b$, we have $aAb\subseteq\mathfrak a\cap \mathfrak b$. As the latter is a prime ideal and $a\notin\mathfrak a\cap \mathfrak b$, we conclude $b\in\mathfrak a\cap \mathfrak b\subseteq \mathfrak a$, in other words $\mathfrak b\subseteq \mathfrak a$.
Similarly, if $a\in \mathfrak a$, then $aAa\in\mathfrak a^2$ implies $a\in\mathfrak a^2$, i.e. $\mathfrak a=\mathfrak a^2$.

Comment: Since the user has specified that noncommutative rings are under consideration, it's likely that the definition for noncommutative prime ideals will have to be used. (Ideals satisfying the commutative definition of prime are called "completely prime", and are usually a proper subset of the collection of prime ideals of a noncommutative ring.) I could be wrong about the user's intention though, so be prepared to disregard this if that is the case :)

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks, I adjusted accordingly, I hope.

Comment: Sure, that defintion works, and now everything is good :)