# If $V$ is a vector space over a division ring $K$, and $A=\mathrm{End}_K(V)$, then every quotient ring of $A$ is a prime ring

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

Let $K$ be a division ring, let $V=V_{K}$ a vector space over $K$, and let $A=\mathrm{End}_{K}(V)$. Could anyone give me an idea of ​​how to prove that every quotient ring of $A$ is a prime ring?

Comment: What's your definition of a *prime ring*? My first instinct would be to assume that a prime ring is a ring additively generated by the multiplicative neutral element, but that does not seem to apply. Do you mean *prime ring* = *simple ring* = a ring with no non-trivial 2-sided ideals?

Comment: for me, a ring A is called prime if the ideal ring (0) is an ideal
prime

Comment: Hmm, $(0)$ is a prime ideal if and only if the ring has no zero-divisors. The ring $A$ is a quotient of itself, and it has zero divisors, so this is not the case here. I rather suspect that something is lost in translation.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No, the question is completely fine. When working with noncommutative rings, you need to stick to the general definition of [prime ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal#Prime_ideals_for_noncommutative_rings).

Comment: Ahh! Thanks rschwieb. Sorry all, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

(The question clearly is asking about quotients by proper ideals.)

The ideal structure of this sort of ring is very simple (although it will take some work for you to show that it is true.) It turns out that the proper ideals of this ring form a chain, and they are exactly of the form $I_\alpha=\{f\in A\mid \dim_K(Im(f))\leq\alpha\}$ where $\alpha$ denotes a cardinal, $\omega\leq \alpha<\dim_K(V)$ if $\dim_K(V)$ is infinite, and $0$ if $\dim_K(V)<\omega$ (is finite, naturally because in that case it's just a matrix ring over a division ring, which is simple, hence it trivially has all factor rings prime).

So you can break this task into parts:

1. Show that each $I_\alpha$ is an ideal of $A$.
2. Show that each $I_\alpha$ is a *prime* ideal of $A$.
3. Show that the $I_\alpha$ are the *only* ideals.

Then you will be done: the quotient by any of these prime ideals creates a prime ring.

---

FYI, there is a connection to this question which might furnish an alternative proof: [Exercise about prime ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395882/exercise-about-prime-ideals/396291#396291). The ring you are talking about is an example of a ring with all ideals idempotent and forming a chain.

It is an elementary exercise to show that $A$ is [von Neumann regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular). Further, it is elementary to show that every ideal of a VNR ring is idempotent. You can use this to replace point #2 above, because with #1 and #3, the linked question gives you that the ideals are prime. However, it's probably just as easy to prove they are prime directly :)

Comment: I'll keep following the question until everything is clear or I think of a way to simplify things :)

Comment: I remember thinking that the definition of prime to use for this ring is "$aAb\subseteq P$ implies $a\in P$ or $b\in P$", but in fact you might find one of the other definitions to be easier...